# Python - How to repeat a row of data from a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I thought this would be fairly simple but I am stuck. I am trying to repeat a row of data based upon a population field. For example, if the population is 921, the row needs to be repeated 921 times, and then move to the next row and repeat based upon the population. The csv file does have a header. I tried removing that and ran into problems so I put the header back.

```
i = 0
while i < pop:
    if pop == 'F21_64':
        break
    else:
        # writerow
        i += 1
```

I keep getting this error code. IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: There is no way this code produces an `IndexError`. Also, how would you ever compare `i < pop` if `pop == 'F21_64'` would ever be true? Please read this help page: [mcve].

Comment: Note that if you csv file contains  well formed header, the `csv.DictReader` will handle it appropriately. If you know that pop is a number, you repeat something that many times via a `for _ in range(pop): do stuff` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You left a lot to assumption but i'll try to answer. For one thing, it is not clear what you want to do with the pop, other than you want to do something the amount of times of its value (print to screen, output to file???) I will assume print to screen.

I imagine you are trying to do something like this: (lets assume your population field is in column 2)

```
for row in rows[1:]:            #dont look at the header row
    pop = row.split(',')[1]     #isolate just the pop value
    popvalue = int(pop)         #convert to int
    for i in range(0,popvalue): #for the number of the value...
        print row               #do the thing you want with the entire row
```